# How exactly are function values ('function pointers') implemented in Go?

Tags: go, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

From [the documentation for `reflect.Value.Pointer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Pointer):

> If v's Kind is Func, the returned pointer is an underlying code pointer, but not necessarily enough to identify a single function uniquely. The only guarantee is that the result is zero if and only if v is a nil func Value.

It seems clear that function-valued variables must contain more than just a  code pointer.  Given that Go supports method pointers, this is hardly surprising - but what is the actual underlying implementation?

(And how does it differ, if at all, for function values created using reflection?  See comment [in the source for Value.Pointer()](http://golang.org/src/reflect/value.go?s=38217:38249#L1238).)

Answer (score 1):

The "New Implementation" section of [the design document](http://golang.org/s/go11func) describes how function pointers are represented.